# Did George Bush take over a year of leave as President?

Tags: united-states, politics

[This image from Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/1404986179713522/photos/a.1405119663033507.1073741829.1404986179713522/1641174956094642/?type=1) claims that "George Bush had America on autopilot for more than a year", followed by a number of presidential vacation days for various American presidents, with the Democrat presidents (Obama: 160, Clinton: 174) having less than half the vacation days as the Republican presidents (Bush: 405, Reagan: 349).

[image]

Did George Bush in fact take over a year of presidential leave, and are the number of leave days for the other presidents accurate?